# PL/SQL region Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a database that contains information about several institutions, these institutions are displayed in a pl/sql region. When a specific institution name is clicked, it will be redirected to a new "Details" page. The problem I am facing is that each institution should have certain images(stored in application files) that should be displayed in the Details page, is it possible?

I hope my question is understandable.

Note: The coding should be in a PL/SQL region.

Comment: What version of APEX are you using? What is a "PL/SQL Region"? Per the docs here are the region types in APEX: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/ui_region.htm#HTMDB06003 How are you displaying the institutions in the region?: Interactive Report, Classic Report or Interactive Grid? Images are stored in App File - does this mean flat files stored in the OS or in the Database? And what does "Application file" mean?  How do will you know what app files to retrieve for a given institution? If you want us to take time to help you on this forum, then help us help you.

Comment: I am using APEX 5.1.  I have created a region using pl/sql code in a page called "Details page", that displays all the information of the institution. There is a requirement to add some images to the "Details page", and those images should be changing according the chosen institution. So the question is how the images are going to be displayed?

Comment: App File is a static applications files that is used to store the uploaded images.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705364/linking-to-a-file-in-oracle-apex