# JS file loading failed in in oracle apex application

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I have added a java script file, named 'dtformat.js' in my oracle apex application. The file was added inside the Static Application Files directory. 
I added the file in my page using the code

```
 <script src="#APP_IMAGES#dtformat.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>
```

The console log shows an error,

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “#WORKSPACE/r/140/files/static/v74/dtformat.js”. 1 f:471
```

Then I found something at the location of static files. The size of the uploaded file shows 833, all the other files show 100KB,21KB,300KB as the file size, but this file- dtformat.js shows 833 and not 833KB. KB is excluded. What might be causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the path: why `#WORKSPACE` string is in the path?

```
#WORKSPACE/r/140/files/static/v74/dtformat.js
```

Comment: Sorry sir, it was my ip address+workspace name. That is why I replaced it to #WORKSPACE

Comment: Can you open this file in the browse?

Comment: Will check it tomorrow. It is night here. But what may be the reason that my uploaded file doesn't show size in KB?

Comment: No, I think the size is not the problem. You need to certify if the correct file was uploaded and if you can open it in the browser with the url gererated by this "#APP_IMAGES#dtformat.js".

Comment: Will check it next  day.

Comment: checked it and it is the url as you said, which is not accessible

Comment: I don't know why this happening... 
do you have other files on Static Application Files directory? can you open it in the browser?

Comment: This was my first file. I think it might be some permission or configuration issue

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705364/linking-to-a-file-in-oracle-apex